# Возможно ли в Битриксе менять права доступа к конкретному элементу инфоблока?

Tags: битрикс, доступ, crm

Имеется некий пользователь, который может создать элемент инфоблока со своими личными данными. То есть, он является автором конкретной записи. Необходимо сделать так, чтоб этот автор смог разрешать другим конкретным пользователям редактировать эту же запись.

Вопрос состоит в том, **возможно ли** вообще в Битриксе менять права доступа **конкретной записи**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, все-таки **возможно** редактировать права доступа к конкретному элементу инфоблока для конкретного пользователя. Описано это в данной [теме форума](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/forums/messages/forum6/topic43553/message235033/#message235033) Битрикса. Экспериментальным путем это было проверено.
Доступы будут редактироваться при включенном "расширенном режиме" уже при редактировании самого элемента инфоблока (из админки или в режиме правки со странцы сайта).

**1.Заходим в панель редактирования элемента инфоблока:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**2.Добавляем нужного пользователя,воспользовавшись поиском:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Штатно можно настроить только групповой доступ к инфоблоку, разделения по конкретным пользователям нет.

Однако вы можете проверять права пользователя на редактирование внутри формы добавления/изменения элемента инфоблока: http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=5258

Также никто не мешает сделать вам свою собственную страницу с использованием встроенных компонентов добавления/редактирования элементов инфоблока `bitrix:iblock.element.add.form` и проверками доступа.

Comment: В общем-то именно интересовало, есть ли такая возможность. За идею с проверкой на редактирование спасибо, быть может удастся с ней что-то сделать (проблема в том, что непосвященные не должны даже видеть эти данные,не только редактировать). Посмотрю ещё, что можно сделать с собственной страницей